# How to access actors from receptionist in non-actor classes using Akka Java?

Tags: java, akka

I have different actors running as part of Akka systems having different types. How can I find an actor from non-actor class having System object using receptionist. I don't have direct reference or any way to pass the reference to non-actor class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Thankfully I could come up with generic and elegant solution using Java AKKA and Receptionist !!

```
private <T> CompletableFuture<ActorRef<T>> findActor(ActorSystem<Void> system, ServiceKey<T> actorKey) {
    ActorRef<Command> receptionist = system.receptionist();
    Duration askTimeout = Duration.ofSeconds(3);
    CompletionStage<Listing> result = AskPattern.ask(
            receptionist,
            replyTo -> Receptionist.find(actorKey, replyTo),
            askTimeout,
            system.scheduler());

    return result.toCompletableFuture().thenApplyAsync(
            (reply) -> {
                if (reply != null && reply instanceof Listing) {
                    return reply.getServiceInstances(actorKey).stream().findFirst().get();
                }
                return null;
            }).exceptionally((Throwable ex) -> {
                return null;
            });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, do you know any reason why the an empty set maybe being returned? Is there a way to check if an actor actually registered with the receptionist?

Comment: That's a very good question @PyWalker2797. I haven't come across anything around receptionist which will give us if actor is registered as receptionist being an actor only thing you can do is to ask/tell asynchronously.

Comment: I think with logging you can, i use log4j, with setting = debug it logs when an actor is registered with receptionist

Answer (score 1):

It would look something like (apologies if the Java is atrocious):

```java
// TargetActor.Command is just a placeholder
ActorSystem<Void> system;
ServiceKey<TargetActor.Command> key;

CompletionStage<Receptionist.Listing> result =
    AskPattern.ask(
        system.receptionist(),
        replyTo -> Receptionist.find(key, replyTo),
        Duration.ofSeconds(10),  // ask will fail if no reply received in this time
        system.scheduler()
    );
```

You can then use the usual `CompletionStage` methods (e.g. `whenComplete` and friends) to extract the `Receptionist.Listing` and take appropriate action.

Comment: I have updated the question to be more focused on solving single problem. I hope now it is more clear for reopeing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is Akka's documentation for interacting with actors outside of the actor system.

There is a tab for `Java`.

https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/interaction-patterns.html#request-response-with-ask-from-outside-an-actor

[image]

Comment: This document doesn't capture anything about receptionist

Comment: @saumilsdk - fair point. I did find this example from `Akka` and it appears you came up with a similar solution.

https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/main/akka-actor-typed-tests/src/test/java/akka/actor/typed/receptionist/ReceptionistApiTest.java

Comment: One more thing is that I could use the generic solution for actor and non-actor classes in synchronous fashion. I found my solution very useful now to find different typed actors. Feel free to upvote my solution if you like.